# SQL Query from a single table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I would like to do two things but I've goten stuck.

**First of all** I would like to write a **SQL** statement to show me all the sport and all competition days each sport has. The table `Event` looks like this

```
Competitor ID  sports   branch         distance   men's/women    
  1            Running  Long-Distance  50000        MEN
```

I also have an Table named `EventDay` which has `CompetitorID`, `date` ,`arena` and `spectators`.

```
CompetitorID  Date       Arena      Spectators
1             08/11/11   Olympus    500
```

There is obviously going to be an join statment here but I cant get it to work.

In the next table below I would like to get out exactly how mand gold medals the invidual countries have goten from the branch Athletics. I would also like it to be devided in the sex and sorted after the name of the country.

```
Land         Sex           Ammount gold
USA           L                   2
USA           M                   4
Ryss          L                   3
Ryss          H                   2
```

Comment: I don't get what you mean... The structure you have is the desired result. Do you have another structure that you want to get data from?

Comment: He has a previous question with more info.

Comment: @Mihai This should be mentioned and probably it would be a nice idea to provide a link for all to see...

Comment: @Mihai: nice catch, I've copied the extra info over and marked the old question as duplicate.

Comment: Where does the country & medal information come from?  It's not in the `Event` and `EventDay` tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TRY THIS

```
SELECT  Country,Sex
,       sum(AmountGold) as TotalGold
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY 
        Country,Sex
ORDER BY 
        Country,Sex
```

I think this is what you need

Comment: Thanks for the reply!What I get out from this is Ammount evrey country gold has ordered by the country and the sex. But there are 2 questions in this posts. I'm sorry If I confused people with this, the first thing I would like to get out from the two tables "Event" and "EventDay" is to print type of sport and all dates those sports are running and for it to show what arena they are on and how amny spectators. But you'r answer was correct when it came to the SQL query in getting out how many gold medals they have.

Comment: I will edit the answer, but please clarify CompetitorID is for a participant, there can be multiple participant in your event table ??

Comment: A CompetitorID is a specific person for example achilles has CompetitorID 1 Clark has CompetitorID 2. Each CompetitorID  is unique and is only declared to one person. I dont have the person Table writen down but it contains CompetitorID, name, cellphone and adress etc. And yes there can be multiple CompetitorID in the table containing different sport etc. Hope it clarified something.

Answer (score 0):

```
select  Country
,       Sex
,       sum(case when MedalType = 'Gold' then 1 else 0 end) as AmountGold
from    YourTable
group by
        Country
,       Sex
order by
        AmountGold desc
```

Comment: You forgot the order by.

Comment: Where did he indicate he had a MedalType column, or is this some sort of homework question where there's a canned answer?

Comment: He has a previous question with more info.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNTRY, 
       SUM(AMOUNT_GOLD) AS TOTAL_GOLD 
FROM   ATHLETICS 
GROUP  BY LAND, 
          SEX 
ORDER  BY LAND
```